# How can I list all packages which version is newer than official repositories'?

Tags: package-management, repository

Some PPAs like the defunct getdeb or nilarimogard (or even proposed) may bring a lot of specific versions when one recklessly runs an update/upgrade with those activated.

Thus, removing the PPA or the repository might not be sufficient to get rid of these experimental versions.

Once I only activate official repositories, how can I CLI get a list of packages which version is higher than the official repositories one ?

Comment: you can use `ppa-purge` to remove a ppa and remove/downgrade the packages installed from it.

Comment: Hi, `ppa-purge` will only work if the ppa is in the same version : I've seen numerous cases where it was not functional.

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/252333/list-all-packages-from-a-repository-in-ubuntu-debian

Comment: I may answer myself to my question : will `apt-forktracer -v` do the job ?

@RoVo : not exactly related : for instance getdeb is now on 404 : we will not get anything from it !